# EclipseLink e JPA

Tags: java, web-service, jpa

Tenho problemas ao tentar gravar informações no banco de dados, em um simples WS com JPA, EclipseLink e banco Postgresql.

Consigo buscar dados e apresenta-los como json no browser com metodos GET, porém estou presisando também gravar dados(POST) e neste momento recebe mensagem de erro:

> ```
> Info: [EL Info]: 2017-01-04 09:12:44.568--ServerSession(1619327197)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
> Info: [EL Info]: connection: 2017-01-04 09:12:45.542--ServerSession(1619327197)--file:/D:/Documents/Projetos NetBeans/app/target/app/WEB-INF/classes/_persist-unit login successful
> Severe: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
> Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
> at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.throwCheckTransactionFailedException(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:87)
> at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.checkForTransaction(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:50)
> at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.checkForTransaction(EntityManagerImpl.java:2041)
> at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:863)
> at br.com.bigfarma.app.service.ProductService.addProduct(ProductService.java:32)
> at br.com.bigfarma.app.resourse.ProductResource.addProduct(ProductResource.java:37)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)...
> ```

**PRODUCTSERVICE:**

```
package br.com.bigfarma.app.service;

import br.com.bigfarma.app.entity.TbProduto;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.FlushModeType;

public class ProductService extends AbstractEntityManager {

public Collection<TbProduto> getAllProducts() {
    return getEm().createQuery(TbProduto.BASE_QUERY).getResultList();
}

public TbProduto addProduct(TbProduto tbProduto) {
    EntityManager em = getEm();
    em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
    EntityTransaction et = getEm().getTransaction();
    try {
        et.begin();
        if(!em.contains(tbProduto)){
            em.persist(tbProduto);
            em.flush(); //LOCAL DO ERRO
        }
        et.commit();
        return tbProduto;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

A IDE é o Netbeans 8.1 com GlassFish 4.0 e Jersey 2.25

Comment: Por qual motivo você tem que usar FlushModeType.COMMIT e o método flush depois do persist?

Comment: @Henrique Luiz, bom dia. Eu estou usando isto pois quando mandei este código tinha feito de acordo um tutorial que vi dizia para utilizar este FlushModeType para evitar o erro que estou tendo, mas como pode ver não evita nada rs. Se eu fizer apenas o commit não dá erro mas também não persiste nada no meu banco de dados, lendo alguns posts eu vi o pessoal dizendo para usar este método flush(). PS: Já tentei sem o FlushModeType porém mesmo assim o erro acontece. Abs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eu mesmo resolvi o problema, foi apenas uma falta de atenção minha no meu método addProduct eu estava fazendo isso: 
EntityManager em = getEm();
em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
EntityTransaction et = **getEm()**.getTransaction();
Ou seja, estava setando um EntityManager(em) mas pegando a transação de um novo entity manager(getEm). Outra coisa que fiz também foi substituir o em.flush() por em.merge() e remover o em.setFlushMode que não estava servindo para nada, com isso, consegui inserir dados sem problema!

Código atualiza do método addProduct:

```
public TbProduto addProduct(TbProduto tbProduto) {
    EntityManager em = getEm();
    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        if (!em.contains(tbProduto)) {
            em.persist(tbProduto);
            em.merge(tbProduto);
        }
        transaction.commit();
        return tbProduto;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Grande abraço.